# Find number of solutions of $2^x$+$3^x$+$4^x$=$5^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Find number of solutions of
$$2^x+3^x+4^x=5^x$$
I tried using graphs but don't know how to draw graph of L.H.S.

Comment: are you allowed to use calculus concepts like differentiation?

Comment: $x=-\infty$ is good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as

$$f(x)=\left({2\over5}\right)^x + \left({3\over5}\right)^x + \left({4\over5}\right)^x = 1$$

Since the fractions being exponentiated are all less than $1$, $f$ is a strictly decreasing function of $x$, hence can take the value $1$ at most once.  It's clear that $f(0)=3\gt1$ and $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, so $f(x)=1$ has *exactly* one solution.  If you need to narrow it down, note that $f(2)=(4+9+16)/25=29/25\gt1$ while $f(3)=(8+27+64)/125=89/125\lt1$, so the single solution lies in the range $2\lt x\lt3$.

Comment: Quite neat. Up Vote $0$k. Bisection Method in $\large\left[2,3\right]$.

Comment: I would prefer another numerical method than Bisection. But the idea is very neat, both the bisection and newton has a faster converges.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate form: $2^x+2^{2x}+3^x=5^x$

plotting graph using wolfram:
 $x\approx2.37329$

So there's just one solution.

Comment: I need to plot without wolfram if it comes in a test.So please tell some method for rough sketching the graph of L.H.S.

Comment: maybe just plugin numbers? the graphs are always positive, that you should know. they are all exponential graphs, that is also apparent. and such graphs can only have up to one intersection point in the first quadrant. I mean, it's not possible for one of the graphs to swerve backwards/forwards and intersect again. intersection would be due to different gradients. It doesn't seem like a question that should be asked on a test.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it with the intermediate value theorem.

Suppose $f(x) = 2^x + 3^x + 4^x$ and $g(x) = 5^x$. Both are continuous and differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We see that $f(0) = 1 < 3 = g(0)$ and $f(3) = 99 < 125 = g(3)$. So there is at least one solution to $f(x) = g(x)$. Let us call the smallest solution to the equation $z$. We see that

$$
f^{(k)}(x) = (\ln 2)^k \cdot 2^x + (\ln 3)^k \cdot 3^x + (\ln 4)^k \cdot 4^x
$$
and
$$
g^{(k)}(x) = (\ln 5)^k \cdot 5^x.
$$
Now we see that
\begin{align*}
f^{(k)}(z) &< (\ln 5)^k \cdot ( 2^z + 3^z + 4^z) \\
&= (\ln 5)^k \cdot 5^z \\
&= g^{(k)}(z),
\end{align*}

so we know the curves cross rather than being tangential. For values of $x \geq z$, we see that $f(x) < g(x)$ and $f'(x) < g'(x)$, so there cannot be any other solutions to $f(x) = g(x)$. Therefore, there is only one solution.

Answer (score 1):

$2^x$+$3^x$+$4^x$=$5^x$

- now x cannot be odd because 5|$2^x$+$3^x$ for all odd x.then 5|$4^x$.this cannot be possible.
- so we consider x=2a.now $4^a$$\equiv$$\pm$1(mod 5) and $9^a$$\equiv$$\pm$1(mod 5) and $16^a$$\equiv$1(mod 5)
- so $2^x$+$3^x$+$4^x$$\equiv$$\pm$1$\pm$1+1(mod 5)
- so we have 5|$\pm$1$\pm$1+1.so this cannot be possible
- so x is not even also.so the equation have no solution